# How does Java Hashtable calculate where to place an element based on hashcode?

Tags: java, hash, hashtable, hashcode

In Java, Hashtable has buckets whose quantity is equal to its capacity. Now how does it determine that it has to store an object in a particular bucket? I know it uses hashcode of the object but hashcode is a weird long string, what does hashtable do to the hashcode to determine place of entry?

Comment: `but hashcode is a weird long string` - no. `hashCode()` returns an `int`.

Comment: A _hash code_ may be anything, but in Java the hash code is simply an `int`.

Comment: Have you taken a look at `HashTable`'s source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementation-dependent (as in, if you rely on it working this way, your code is broken; the things HashMap guarantees are spelled out in its javadoc, and none of what I'm about to type is in there):

hashes are just a number. Between about -2billion and +2billion. That 'long weird string' you see is just a more convenient way to show it to you.

First, the higher digits of that number are mixed into the lower digits (actually, the higher bits are XORed into the lower ones): 12340005 is turned into 12341239.

Then, that number is divided by how many buckets there currently are, but the result is tossed out, it's the remainder we are interested in. This remainder is necessarily 0 or higher, and never more than '# of buckets there are', so always points exactly at one of the buckets.

That's the bucket that the object goes into.

if buckets grow too large, a resizing is done.

For more, well, HashMap is open source, as is HashSet - just have a look.

Comment: Wilfred might have not intended this but the question is specifically about [HashTable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) not [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank You very much, I just wanted to know exactly this.

Answer (score 2):

For behavior as of jdk7 see:

https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/Hashtable.java#L358

```
int index = (hash & 0x7FFFFFFF) % tab.length;
```

This is a common technique for hash tables. First bit is discarded (to make the value positive). The index is the [remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) from division by table size.

Answer (score 2):

> I know it uses hashcode of the object but hashcode is a weird long string, what does hashtable do to the hashcode to determine place of entry?

A hashcode is not a "weird long string".  It is a 32 bit signed integer.

(I think you are confusing the hashcode and what you get when you call `Object::toString` ... which is a string consisting of a hashcode AND a Java internal type name.)

So what `HashMap` and `HashTable` (and `HashSet` and `LinkedHashMap`) actually do is:

- call `hashCode()` to get the 32 bit integer,
- perform some implementation-specific mangling<sup>1</sup> on the integer,
- convert the mangled integer to a non-negative integer by removing the sign bit,
- compute an array index (for the bucket) as `value % array.length` where `array` is the hash table's current array of hash chains (or trees).

---

<sup>1 - Some implementations of `HashMap` / `HashTable` perform some simple / cheap bitwise mangling.  The purpose is to reduce clustering in the case that the low few bits of the hashcode values are not evenly distributed.</sup>